# Unable to post value from bootstrap-wysiwyg text editor in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, codeigniter, post

I am using **bootstrap-wysiwyg text editor** in my form, and I am not able to post value in controller

**View** :

```
<form id="demo-form2" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/post/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Post Details<span style="color:red"> <?php echo form_error('details'); ?></span></label>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">   
                  <div id="alerts"></div>
                  <div class="btn-toolbar editor" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="fa fa-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="fa fa-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                          <a data-edit="fontSize 5">
                            <p style="font-size:17px">Huge</p>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a data-edit="fontSize 3">
                            <p style="font-size:14px">Normal</p>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a data-edit="fontSize 1">
                            <p style="font-size:11px">Small</p>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>



                  </div>

                  <div id="editor" class="editor-wrapper"></div>

                  <textarea  id="descr" name="descr" style="display:none;"></textarea>

                 </div>


                      </div>
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form>
```

And my controller

```
print_r($_POST); exit;
```

On searching, I have founded answers like
[Solution for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623865/bootstrap-responsive-wyswig-editor-doesnt-send-input-data-to-php)

But I don't know how to implement this in my condition. I am getting all the other values expect value in text-area.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This form submit never get data from the editor

Comment: Side note: The fields will not be sent to the server with `display:none`, but they will be with `visibility:hidden` and `position:absolute`.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam any solution for that

Comment: Check my answer @DavidNinan

Comment: You can check my answer @DavidNinan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the editor contents and replace the value of `editor_contents` on the submit.

```
<form name="your_form" method="post" onSubmit="document.your_form.editor_contents.value = $('#editor').html()">
<textarea name="editor_contents" style="display:none;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And you can access it on PHP like `$_POST['editor_contents']`

This like passing your data on hidden fields.

Comment: Check I have updated the answer. it works perfectly fine for me!

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: I am also facing this same issue. up vote for saving my time thanks

Comment: Wow, I feel great today! Thanks,  @YadhuBabu .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit','#demo-form2',function(){
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['descr'];
        document.getElementById('descr').value = editor.getData();
    })
</script>
```